# C# how to use textbox, abels characters (numbers ) into a listbox to show the count

Tags: c#

i need help to show the failed parts with the numbers used in the textbox and in the labels what is generated

```
 while (
     myString = myString + " SUCCESS: " + myNum1 / 2 / 3 + " vs " + myRandom1 / 2 / 3;
     myString = myString + " Failed: " + myNum1 /2 / 3 + " vs " + myRandom1 / 2 / 3;
     Listbox.Items.Add(myString);
```

I have an issue with the count in `myString = myString + " SUCCESS: " + myNum1 / 2 / 3 + " vs " + myRandom1 / 2 / 3;` and in the  `myString = myString + " Failed: " + myNum1 /2 / 3 + " vs " + myRandom1 / 2 / 3;`
it won't display the numbers used in the mynum1 to 3 which are my textbox where i insert the numbers and it wont display the vs numbers which are the random numbers that are been scanned
[image]

Comment: i hoep i did this right i m new to this idkl how to ask right question i wish i knew how to be more to the subject

Answer (score 1):

i figured out

myString = myString + " SUCCESS: " + myNum1 + myNum2 + myNum3 + " vs " + myRandom1 + myRandom2 + myRandom3;

myString = myString + " Failed: " + myNum1 + myNum2 + myNum3 + " vs " + myRandom1 + myRandom2 + myRandom3;